# Status variable returns nullPointerException (Android)

Tags: java, android, variables, nullpointerexception, status

I have been following a tutorial (http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-working-with-google-places-and-maps-tutorial/) in order to make a listview display nearest restaurant to your location in radius of 5km.

However i keep getting an error, in my Runnable it says that the status variable is null. I don't really understand why this error pops up. Can you guys give me a short explanation and help find a solution??

PlacesList.java

```
public class PlacesList implements Serializable {

    public String status;
    public List<Place> results;

}
```

DisplayLocations.java

```
public class DisplayLocations extends Activity {

    boolean isInternetPresent = false;

    ConnectionDetector cd;
    GooglePlaces googlePlaces;
    PlacesList nearPlaces;
    GPSTracker gps;

    Button shownOnMap;
    ProgressDialog pDialog;

    ListView lv;

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> placesListItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    public static String KEY_REFERENCE = "reference";
    public static String KEY_NAME = "name";
    public static String KEY_VICINITY = "vicinity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_locations);

        cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

        isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();
        if(!isInternetPresent){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Get a working connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        gps = new GPSTracker(DisplayLocations.this);

        if(gps.canGetLocation()){

        }else{
            gps.showSettingsAlert();
        }

        lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        shownOnMap = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_show_map);

        new LoadPlaces().execute();

        shownOnMap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                /*
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PlacesMapActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("user_latitude", Double.toString(gps.getLatitude()));
                i.putExtra("user_longitude", Double.toString(gps.getLongitude()));
                i.putExtra("near_places", nearPlaces);
                startActivity(i);
                */
            }
        });

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String reference = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.reference)).getText().toString();
                /*
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingePlaceActivity.class);
                in.putExtra(KEY_REFERENCE, reference);
                startActivity(in);
                */
            }
        });
    }


    class LoadPlaces extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(DisplayLocations.this);
            pDialog.setMessage(Html.fromHtml("<b>Search</b><br/>Loading Places..."));
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            googlePlaces = new GooglePlaces();

            try{
                String types = "cafe|restaurant";
                double radius = 5000;
                nearPlaces = googlePlaces.search(gps.getLatitude(), gps.getLongitude(), radius, types);

            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            pDialog.dismiss();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    String status = nearPlaces.status;

                    if (status.equals("OK")){
                        if(nearPlaces.results != null){
                            for (Place p : nearPlaces.results){
                                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                map.put(KEY_REFERENCE, p.reference);
                                map.put(KEY_NAME, p.name);
                                placesListItems.add(map);
                            }
                            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(DisplayLocations.this, placesListItems, R.layout.location_listview_item,
                                    new String[]{KEY_REFERENCE, KEY_NAME}, new int[]{R.id.reference, R.id.name});
                            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                        }
                    }
                    else if(status.equals("ZERO_RESULTS")){
                        // Zero results found
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Results", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    }
                    else if(status.equals("UNKNOWN_ERROR"))
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unknown error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    }
                    else if(status.equals("OVER_QUERY_LIMIT"))
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Query limit reached !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    }
                    else if(status.equals("REQUEST_DENIED"))
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Request denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    }
                    else if(status.equals("INVALID_REQUEST"))
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid request", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_display_locations, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

GooglePlaces.java

```
public class GooglePlaces {

    private static final HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = new NetHttpTransport();

    private final String API_KEY = "AIzaSyCxY1X7hC7SOab7V3GbWd1u42fGThgYOhg";

    //GooglePlaces search URL
    private static final String PLACES_SEARCH_URL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?";
    private static final String PLACES_TEXT_SEARCH_URL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?";
    private static final String PLACES_DETAILS_URL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?";

    private double mLatitiude;
    private double mLongitude;
    private double mRadius;

    public PlacesList search(double latitude, double longitude, double radius, String types) throws Exception{
            this.mLatitiude = latitude;
            this.mLongitude = longitude;
            this.mRadius = radius;

            try {
                HttpRequestFactory httpRequestFactory = createRequestFactory(HTTP_TRANSPORT);
                HttpRequest request = httpRequestFactory.buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(PLACES_SEARCH_URL));
                request.getUrl().put("key", API_KEY);
                request.getUrl().put("location", mLatitiude + "," + mLongitude);
                request.getUrl().put("radius", mRadius); // in meters
                request.getUrl().put("sensor", "false");
                if (types != null)
                    request.getUrl().put("types", types);

                PlacesList list = request.execute().parseAs(PlacesList.class);
                // Check log cat for places response status
                Log.d("Places Status", "" + list.status);
                return list;

            } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
                Log.e("Error:", e.getMessage());
                return null;
            }

    }

    public PlaceDetails getPlaceDetails(String reference) throws Exception{
        try{
            HttpRequestFactory httpRequestFactory = createRequestFactory(HTTP_TRANSPORT);
            HttpRequest request = httpRequestFactory.buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(PLACES_DETAILS_URL));
            request.getUrl().put("reference", reference);
            request.getUrl().put("key", API_KEY);
            request.getUrl().put("sensor",false);

            PlaceDetails place = request.execute().parseAs(PlaceDetails.class);
            return place;

        }catch (HttpResponseException e){
            throw e;
        }
    }

    public static HttpRequestFactory createRequestFactory(final HttpTransport transport){
        return transport.createRequestFactory(new HttpRequestInitializer() {
            @Override
            public void initialize(HttpRequest request) throws IOException {
                HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
                httpHeaders.setUserAgent("Application Test");
                request.setHeaders(httpHeaders);
                    JsonObjectParser parser = new JsonObjectParser(new JsonFactory() {
                        @Override
                        public JsonParser createJsonParser(InputStream in) throws IOException {
                            return null;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public JsonParser createJsonParser(InputStream in, Charset charset) throws IOException {
                            return null;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public JsonParser createJsonParser(String value) throws IOException {
                            return null;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public JsonParser createJsonParser(Reader reader) throws IOException {
                            return null;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public JsonGenerator createJsonGenerator(OutputStream out, Charset enc) throws IOException {
                            return null;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public JsonGenerator createJsonGenerator(Writer writer) throws IOException {
                            return null;
                        }
                    });
                    request.setParser(parser);
            }

        });
    }
}
```

Line 132 of DisplayLocations.java is :

```
String status = nearPlaces.status;
```

This is the stacktrace :

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'java.lang.String com.example.dell.exampleapplication.PlacesList.status' on a null object reference
        at com.example.dell.exampleapplication.DisplayLocations$LoadPlaces$1.run(DisplayLocations.java:132)
        at android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:5517)
        at com.example.dell.exampleapplication.DisplayLocations$LoadPlaces.onPostExecute(DisplayLocations.java:129)
        at com.example.dell.exampleapplication.DisplayLocations$LoadPlaces.onPostExecute(DisplayLocations.java:98)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5834)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1388)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1183)
```

Any help and explanation would be appreciated.

Thanks, have a nice day.

Comment: post full Placcelist Class.

Comment: @ImtiyazKhalani, what i posted is the full PlacesList class. :)

Comment: post line 132 from DisplayLocations class.

Comment: Are you getting value for nearPlaces variable?

Comment: @rajatmehra i added the line. Keshav1234 GooglePlaces class must be handling that for me. However it seems it's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

nearPlaces.status = ... (the status: probably from GooglePlaces) in doInBackGround

then you can do:
String status = nearPlaces.status; in onPostExecute

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Your comment helps guiding me in the right way. I added GooglePlaces class, there it must be going wrong. I can't find the error. Can you help further?

Comment: String status = nearPlaces.status; --> You ask for the status but you never did nearPlaces.status = ...

So you want to GET the value, but never SET it. Thats your mistake.

Comment: Are you sure? Because in doInBackground i have nearPlaces = googlePlaces.search(gps.getLatitude(), gps.getLongitude(), radius, types); that should do it right? Or am i missing on something? Can you show how to do it right please?

Comment: Yeah but the variable STATUS of the object nearPlaces is still NULL... Your object is not null but your status is. So you can't do String status = nearPlaces.status.
DO this test: nearPlaces.status = "OK"; put this under your nearPlaces = ...

Comment: If look at onPostExecute after public void run i do, String status = nearPlaces.status; Thank you for thinking with me. But i don't really get the issues

Comment: in doInBackground i cannot cast nearPlaces.status = googlePlaces.search(gps.getLatitude(), gps.getLongitude(), radius, types); Types are not compatible types (required : String, found : exampleapplicate.PlacesList)

Comment: check my new answer and test it :-)

Comment: i did the test however still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

**Add the line**

```
    @Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    googlePlaces = new GooglePlaces();

    try{
        String types = "cafe|restaurant";
        double radius = 5000;
        nearPlaces = googlePlaces.search(gps.getLatitude(), gps.getLongitude(), radius, types);
        nearPlaces.status = "OK"; //Add this line for testing, your code should work now, because status is not NULL anymore. 

    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Getting the same error, String status = nearPlaces.status; this line is apparently still null. I understand the error now thanks to you. However like you say it shouldn't return null now because status = "OK", however it still returns null :s

Comment: PlacesList list = request.execute().parseAs(PlacesList.class);
            // Check log cat for places response status
            Log.d("Places Status", "" + list.status);

What does this log print out? (In your GooglePlaces class)

Comment: Can't find it in the logcat, sorry do not know how to fix it... i am quite new to location, maps and google Places... and Android.